# Install Oracle Secure Enterprise Search (SES) in Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, oracle

I am learning Ubuntu and I need to use it for a "test server" of Oracle SES. I already downloaded the SES from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/search/downloads/linuxx8664soft-085433.html

Unfortunately, I can't manage to install it on Ubuntu 12.04.

Can anyone advise me on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is going to be a very friendly installation even for a seasoned Ubuntu user. When searching for this the lack of topics about Oracle SES with Ubuntu tells it is not going to be easy.

From the installation requirements it states this:

> **Oracle SES Linux Certifications**
>
> Oracle SES is certified to run on the following Linux operating systems:
>
> - Oracle Enterprise Linux 4 (Update 6 or higher to support WebLogic)
> - Oracle Enterprise Linux 5
> - Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4 AS and ES (Update 3 or higher)
> - Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 AS and ES (or later updates)
> - SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10
>     -SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11
>
> These are the only supported distributions and versions. Do not install Oracle SES on other versions of Linux.

---

They do not want you to use it with Ubuntu... So still want it? The link you posted has this to tell you:

> Directions:
>
> 1. Uncompress the file using "unzip", for example: `ses_11_1_2_2_0_linux64_1of2.zip`
> 2. See the [installation guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21698_01/install.1122/e21400/toc.htm#CHDHFAID) for this release
> 3. See all [Enterprise Search documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21698_01/index.htm)

---

Some pointers I found in [this link from 2009](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=935602)...

- Where in the installation manual it says to use "./runInstaller" and if it does not work try ...

  ```
  ./runInstaller -ignoreSysPrereqs
  ```
- If the automatic start does not work you can do it manually with the following commands:

  ```
  export ORACLE_HOME=<your oracle home>
  export ORACLE_SID=<your sid - default is "ses">
  lsnrctl start 
  sqlplus sys/<password> as sysdba
  startup 
  exit
  searchctl start
  ```
- Interesting comment:

  > I've had SES running under Ubuntu 9.0.4 using this method. It was working well enough to do some performance testing, but I wouldn't trust it for a production system or any kind of stability test.

---

If you get this working could you please answer your own question with all the problems you faced and how you solved them?